# How to connect to MS SQL Server 2019 Instance running in Openshift cluster with SSMS via port-forwarding?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Having:

- An Openshift Cluster version 4.8.18 running on the Azure Openshift Service
- A Project in the cluster running a SQL Server 2019 Instance created via `oc new-app` like so:
  `oc new-app mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y -e SA_PASSWORD="securepa$$@asdf" --name sqlserver`
- The instance starts properly according to the pod logs and openshift reports OK readiness and liveliness
- By connecting via `oc rsh` directly to the container, I am able to interact with the database via `sqlcmd`

I am trying to connect to the database instance with SSMS v18.10 on Windows 10 via the kubernetes port-forwarding mechanism following [this post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/use-port-forwarding-to-access-sql-server-running-in-kubernetes) **without success:**

`oc port-forward pod/sqlserver-aaaaaaaaa-aaaaa 1433:1433`

Connections on localhost from SSMS with correct credentials always result in the following error:

```
Cannot connect to localhost.
Additional information:
A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
...
```

Note that:

- I am trying to connect while the `oc port-forward` is running
- I tried disabling the Windows 10 firewall and trying to connect without success
- I tried port forwarding from a web application and it worked with the firewall on with the same cluster

**What am I missing here?**

### UPDATE 1

I have been able to connect to the SQL Server Instance by creating a `service` of type `LoadBalancer` via the External IP created by the service.

Comment: What settings are you using in SSMS to connect? In the Server name field are you typing `127.0.0.1,1433`?

Comment: The linked blog entry seems to expose the container's port 1433 in its Kubernetes template with `containerPort: 1433`. Are you sure you don't need to do something like that with `oc new-app`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am connecting with SSMS by specifying `localhost`, I will give a try to `127.0.0.1,1433`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning After creating the deployment with `oc new-app` I am able to confirm that the port exposed on the pod is 1433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [in the linked post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/use-port-forwarding-to-access-sql-server-running-in-kubernetes) and by [@AlwaysLearning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/70706/alwayslearning) in the comments, you have to connect by refering to localhost by IP(`127.0.0.1`) and not by hostname(`localhost`).